# Need a better way to validate ASP.NET checkboxes using a jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, checkbox

**Problem:**

I want to validate some ASP.NET-checkboxes using the jquery validation plugin (found at: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

**What it's all about:**

It's not possible to set the name attribute of ASP.NET checkboxes (or is it?). It'll automatically be set, when the control is rendered and can be retrieved using

```
<%= emailCheckBox.UniqueID %>
```

So two checkboxes as the following:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="emailAcceptCheckBox" />Email<br />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="phoneAcceptCheckBox" />Phone<br />
```

will render to:

```
<INPUT id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_emailAcceptCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$emailAcceptCheckBox">
<INPUT id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_phoneAcceptCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$phoneAcceptCheckBox">
```

Maybe it's a mess to mix ASP.NET with the jquery validation plugin, but I prefer the jquery validation plugin and it works fine with inputs and other fields.

Problem is, that the jquery validation plugin wants to group the checkboxes using the name-attribute of checkboxes. This name attributes should be equal to all checkboxes and a group.

**What I've done:**

I added a rule to ALL checkboxes using jquery:

```
$("#[id*='AcceptCheckBox']").each(function() { $(this).rules("add", { minchecked: 1 }); });
```

And added my own rule checking for checkboxes:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minchecked",
 function(value, element, param) {
     var noOfChecked = $("#[id*='AcceptCheckBox']:checked").length;
          return noOfChecked >= param;
     },
 "Error");
```

(This rule will apply for checkboxes whose IDs include AcceptCheckBox, but it's okay in this example).

When I call:

```
var result = $("#aspnetForm").validate().form();
```

It returns perfectly if my validation succeeded or failed!

BUT:

1) I don't feel that this is a very clean and nice solution. Any better advice?

2) When I run validate().form() it'll go through ALL my checkboxes and for each of them check all the other checkboxes. That's really not necessary. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Overall, your code does look fine to me. I think you have cleanly handled the asp:checkbox limitation (you can't specify 'name' attribute for asp:checkbox).

Personally, I would use regular HTML checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" ID="emailAcceptCheckBox" name="acceptCheckBox" value="emailAccepted" /><label for="emailAcceptCheckBox">Email</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" ID="phoneAcceptCheckBox" name="acceptCheckBox" value="phoneAccepted" /><label for="phoneAcceptCheckBox">Email</label><br />
```

(I have added a label tag so that user can click on the label (bigger target) to check/uncheck the checkbox.)

Above will simplify your jQuery code.

On your server side code, check Request.Form["acceptCheckBox"] to see what is checked and what is not.

Comment: Hi SolutionYogi

Thank you for the answer.
You're right. It's nicer to make the input boxes with  html-<input>-tags instead of ASP.NET-controls.
But in a specific problem (not the example above) the checkboxes are built serverside and added to a PlaceHolder on the client. So I would like to stay with the ASP.NET-controls.

I just finished making a solution, which is a nice one also. I looked at the validation jquery-plugin and added my own rule and made small hacks here and there, so it now works with ASP.NET-checkboxes also!