# jQuery Validation: validate atleast one checkbox is selected from a list where names are different

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I need to validate that atleast one check box is selected from a list of checkboxes using jQuery Validation Plugin. Since the checkboxes are part of a ASP.NET GridView Control, the names of these checkboxes will be different, which makes setting up the rules for the validation plugin complex since it expects the name for the rule. I have searched around and found the below questions

- [Question 1710486](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710486/jquery-validate-if-one-of-many-checkboxes-is-selected-different-names-using-th)
- [Question 1136507](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136507/need-a-better-way-to-validate-asp-net-checkboxes-using-a-jquery-validation-plugin)

I think the first question is a much better solution, but i still feel that it is not the right way to do. does anybody else have any more options for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about a complex rule that only makes the item required if no other checkboxes have been checked.

```
rules: {
   'require-one': {
       required : {
           depends: function(element) {
                       var allBoxes = $('.require-one');
                       if (allBoxes.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
                          if (allBoxes.eq(element).length != 0) {
                              return true;
                          }
                       }
                       return false;
                    }
       }
    }
}
```

Then you'd apply the `require-one` class to each checkbox in the set.  The first one would be required if none of the boxes where checked.

Comment: @tvanfosson, my scenario is to validate atleast one checkbox is selected, not that only one checkbox is selected (i am not using it as a Radio button Group) Your rule seems to indicate that only one should be selected
i did go the class approach way, the disadvantage seemed to be that the validation will be called for each checkbox, and so will the message, even though i use a container for showing an error message.

Comment: No.  If at least one checkbox is checked, then none are required.  If none are checked, then all are required -- and since they are not checked it will result in a validation error for each.   It does have the disadvantage of having a message for each.

Comment: You could adjust this to also return true for the first element, if none are checked.  I'll adjust.